# Clojure: using *command-line-args* in the script rather than REPL

Tags: clojure

I've clojure running within Eclipse. I want to pass arguments to clojure when running it. In the below the arguments are available in the REPL but not in the script itself. What do I need to do such that in the below typing arg1 in the REPL will return the first argument?

Script:

```
(NS Test)
(def arg1 (nth *command-line-args* 0))
```

After clicking on the Eclipse "Run"...

```
Clojure 1.1.0
1:1 user=> #<Namespace test>
1:2 test=> arg1
nil
1:3 test=> *command-line-args*
("bird" "dog" "cat" "pig")
1:4 test=> (def arg2 (nth *command-line-args* 1))
#'test/arg2
1:5 test=>  arg2
"dog"
1:6 test=>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like maybe your `arg1` is being defined before `*command-line-args*` gets a value.  `*command-line-args*` is in `clojure.core`, so every namespace should be able to see it (unless you define a namespace and specifically tell it to exclude `core` or exclude that var).  I don't know how Eclipse launches a REPL or how/when it loads namespaces or user code, so I don't know the problem.

But you could turn `arg1` into a function, and then it should always return the current value of `*command-line-args*` (since it'll be resolved at runtime, and `*command-line-args*` should have a value by the time you call the function).

```
(defn arg1 [] (nth *command-line-args* 0))
```

Better, if `(nth *command-line-args* 0)` is really that much to type itself (which I don't think it is, really) you could write a better function:

```
(defn ARGV [n] (nth *command-line-args* n))
```

Then use `(ARGV 0)`, `(ARGV 1)` etc.  Keep in mind that vectors are themselves functions of their arguments, so you could just as easily do `(*command-line-args* n)` directly (once you're sure `*command-line-args*` is not `nil`; otherwise you'll get a NullPointerException.)

Using a lot of `def`s to assign names to things at the top-level is usually not idiomatic in Clojure.  If you want to refer to command line arguments locally and just give them a shorter name for a while, there's `let`:

```
(defn foo []
  (let [arg1 (nth *command-line-args* 0)]
    ...))
```

Again, this way `arg1` should get its value at runtime (whenever you call `foo`) so it should work.

Comment: Brian, thanks for the suggestions. It certainly appears to be something with the way the REPL starts in Eclipse; running the script directly works as expected.

FYI, not sure why, but setting defining arg1 as a function doesn't work as I expected. The below is a new script and the output running it directly. 
(ns test)
(println *command-line-args*)
(defn arg1 [] (nth *command-line-args* 0))

and running it...


java -cp /Path_to_jar/clojure.jar clojure.main com.clj cat dog
(cat dog)
#<commie$arg1__12 commie$arg1__12@67e13e07>
(println arg1)